# All companies are either not-for-profit or NPOs: what problems will we face?

Tags: economy

I want all the world's companies to use their profits towards paying their employees a decent wage, keeping company infrastructure up-to-date and evolving, and lowering consumer costs and fees.

What's the downside - what difficulties will we encounter?

Comment: Isn't that what's already happening?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. Please imagine that for a second that I was inventing a world in my head. In this world there exist many countries with cultures, economies, and relationships which may or may not have any basis in real life. Then I ask you, in all seriousness, the question you just asked us. How the heck is anyone supposed to know how to answer? World economies are incredibly complex, and the behavior you're describing would only come about as a result of massive cultural and societal changes, since the real world works in almost exactly the opposite way. How could we know?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception here. A [profit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/profit?s=t) is "the monetary surplus left to a producer or employer after deducting wages, rent, cost of raw materials, etc." In other words, profit is what is left after tending to all the factors you listed.

Comment: @Frostfyre I think the idea is that the companies will reduce the cost of their products rather than having money left over at the end.

Comment: As @AndreiROM pointed out, to properly answer the question, incredible amount of economics knowledge would be necessary to roll up and out, starting from elementary - which I believe is not in scope.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T no, profits go to owners/partners/share-holders

Comment: @AndreiROM I'm not sure, maybe start by comparing the pros and cons of a credit union to a for-profit banking institution perhaps

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, your economy is doomed.

Putting every penny that every company makes immediately to work means that you have no reserve. There's no spare productivity you can use to meet unexpected needs, no leeway in case you don't sell as many widgets as you expect. If an epidemic disease suddenly appears and workers start dropping, there aren't new workers to bring in, you don't have underworked doctors and scientists who can drop what they're doing and work on treating the sick, there aren't as many widgets available for purchase as everyone expected, so fewer people have widgets...

In short, there's no flexibility in the economy. That limits the potential for growth as well as the ability to respond to changes.

What you're talking about is effectively a command economy, and we simply don't have the brainpower or the computer power to properly run one. Even if nothing ever goes wrong, the economy is too complex for us to model; add in even a slight change, and everything goes straight down the toilet.